# Wordpress custom post type taxonomy URL

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm having trouble getting the URL structure for my custom post types & taxonomy. I have a custom post type called projects and a taxonomy of company, I have created projects and added them to the company taxonomies.

The company taxonomies are design,film,advertising & architecture so when I visit a project I want the URL to be websitename/film/projects/projectname but at the moment I just have websitename/projects/projectname

this is my registered custom post type "Movies" and taxonomy "Genres"

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function movies() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Movies', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Movie', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Movies', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Movies', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Movie Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Movie Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Movies', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Movie', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Movie Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'genres'),
        array(
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'movies/%genres%', 'with_front' => false ),
            'has_archive' => 'genres',
            // your other args...
        ),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'movies', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'movies', 0 );

// Register Custom Taxonomy
function genres() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Genres', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Genre', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Genre', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Genres', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        array(
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'movies', 'with_front' => false ),
            // your other args...
        ),
        'query_var'                  => true,
        'publicly_queryable'         => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'genres', array( 'post', 'page', 'movies' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'genres', 0 );

function wpa_show_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'movies' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'genres' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%genres%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_show_permalinks', 1, 2 );
```

Here is my custom taxonomy called "Genres"

Comment: did you try to use the `rewrite` argument? check out the [reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#rewrite)

Comment: The sister site has an answer : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post

Comment: Thankyou for that, I have edited my question to show new CPT & Taxonomy but still cannot get it to show /movies/genre/moviename